# How to change colors systemwide?

Tags: linux, qt, colors

I have a [tiny210](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/tiny210) board with [Qtopia (Qt Extended)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Extended) installed on it and with a display wired to it. The problem is that the colors were wired wrongly and now `red is blue` and `blue is red`.

The colors cannot be rewired so now I have to fix this bug from the OS.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you display `QImage`s, the [rbgSwapped](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#rgbSwapped) function might be helpful. I've got no clue of how to change this system-wide though...

Comment: I managed to swap them for the app developed by me, but I would like to swap them for everything on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

I had to recompile the kernel and in `drivers/video/samsung/s3cfb_fimdfx.c` I had to add:

- `cfg |= 0x20000;` on line 67
- `cfg |= 0x240000;` on line 95.

After this the colors were as expected.

The file will differ from driver to driver, but the fix should be something similar.